# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

The Route is `Route::resource('/admin/post', 'postController');`

in controller the code is

```
public function index()
{
    $s = Singer::where('id','<',5)->get()->name;

    return view("admin.new-post", ['s'=>$s]);
}
```

And the view is

```
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                                <?php foreach ($s as $ss){
                                    echo '<option>'. $ss .'</option>';
                                 }?>

                            </select>
```

I want to list down all the names of singers from data base in select. And the problem is that when I get a single value using `first()` in query instead of `get()` it returns single value correctly widhout any error. but when I use `get()` and in view use `foreach` loop to get all singers then it gives this error. `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name`. I have reviewed code many times but could not understand that what the error is. while there is no problem to get a single name.. please provide me some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller Code

```
public function index()
{
$s = Singer::where('id','<',5)->get();

return view("admin.new-post", ['s'=>$s]);
}
```

View Code

```
<select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">

                            <?php foreach ($s as $ss){
                                echo '<option>'. $ss->name .'</option>';
                             }?>

                        </select>
```

When you use first() you get a single result, when you use get() you are getting a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) of results, even if your searching for one user.